# Reflection of point over line with absolute value

Tags: geometry, functions

Consider a point $(p,q)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm interested in reflecting this point over the line $x+y+10=0$, for example. I know from the formula for the reflection of a point over a line that the reflected point has coordinate $\left(-q-10, -p-10\right)$. However, I'm only interested in reflecting points such that $p+q+10<0$, so all points $(p,q)$ such that $p+q+10\geq 0$ remain $(p,q)$. Is there a way to represent this $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ mapping with only absolute values and without cases?

Comment: Can you figure it out for $y=x$ ($y-x=0$)? If so, a translation and reflection would work for $y=-x-10$.

Comment: Even for $y=x$, it is not that clear to me. This is not a guided question from any textbook I'm reading, it's just a personal interest.

Comment: Would the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) be fine to use? I can come up with something in terms of absolute value only but that expression would be not defined on the line $x + y + 10 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\pmatrix{p \\ q}\mapsto
\pmatrix{
\displaystyle{|p+q+10|+p-q-10\over2}
\\
\displaystyle{|p+q+10|-p+q-10\over2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks! How might I go about understanding the reasoning for the solution?

Comment: More specifically, if the line in question becomes $ax+by+c$ with the same behaviour, the coordinate reflection of a point becomes dependant on both $p$ and $q$. How would this final answer change?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, I went back to this and derived the general form for $ax+by+c=0$ and it is:
$$
\pmatrix{p \\ q} \mapsto
\pmatrix{
\frac{a\left|ap+bq+c\right|+b^2p-abq-ac}{a^2+b^2}
\\
\frac{b\left|ap+bq+c\right|-abp+a^2q-bc}{a^2+b^2}
}
$$
Also, since the original question asked to reflect the point if it is below the line $ax+by+c=0$, to reflect the point above the line, simply change $a|ap+bq+c|$ to $-a|ap+bq+c|$ and $b|ap+bq+c|$ to $-b|ap+bq+c|$ in the equations.